# Creating shapefile with quantity of points using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I need a shapefile able to show the amount of houses in every 100m2 of a region. I don't want any density calculation, I need just the amount of point in each cell in a new shapefile.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is a two step process:

1. Use [Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000) to create a polygon shapefile (or feature class) with each cell 10x10m (100m2)
2. Perform the counts of houses in each cell by following [HowTo:  Count the number of point features within a polygon](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30779)